# izpack and build.properties

Tags: java, ant, installation, izpack

Does anyone know how to pass build properties to izpack in ANT.

I have a working izpack install in ANT and it works fine but I have to remember to manually put in thing like version number etc.. which are in my build.properties file.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference Ant properties using the `@{}` syntax in IzPack install definitions:

```
<installation version="1.0">
      <!-- Ant properties in this file can be referenced with @{},
           otherwise use variables below in installer files with ${} -->
      <info>
        <appname>@{product.name}</appname>
        <appversion>@{product.version}</appversion>
        <uninstaller name="remove.task" path="${INSTALL_PATH}/Uninstall" write="yes"/>
      </info>
...
```

[*Source*](http://izpack.org/documentation/sample-install-definition.html)

Comment: I use     
<target name="installer" description="Build installer">
        <izpack input="install.xml" output="c:/temp/test.jar" basedir="${release.dir}"/>

I don't seem to able to use <appversion>@{release.version}</appversion> which is defined in build.properties

    </target>

Comment: @Dan - where do you hard code the version number?  In your install.xml?  That's where you can refer to Ant properties using the @{} syntax as in the example.

Comment: It's in "build.properties" file.  I have the expression ${release.version} which works fine in build.xml - the question is how to pass those values into install.xml

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in order to propagate all project properties to the the izpack compiler you need to set the **inheritAll** attribute to "**true**".

```
<izpack input="install-definition.xml"
    output="${output.dir}/${product.short.name}-${product.version}-install.jar"
    installerType="standard"
    inheritAll="true"
    basedir="${temp.dir}" />
```

Then in your installation definition file reference the property using @{product.version}

However, I could not find it the documentation so it may inherit more than properties.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. I copy the install to my dist folder and replace at that point.

```
<copy file="install.xml" todir="${output.dir}" overwrite="true">
  <filterset>
    <filter token="release.version" value="${release.version}"/>
  </filterset>
</copy>
```

later on:

```
<target name="installer" description="Build installer" depends="all">
  <izpack input="${output.dir}/install.xml" output="c:/temp/test.jar" basedir="${release.dir}"/>
    </target>
```